# Unity SetActive() function not working from Script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the Hierarchy of my Objects:

```
GameManager
Dice
    Dice1
    Dice2
    Dice3
    Dice4
    Dice5
    Dice6
    Canvas
        Btn
```

I am working on a simple function in the script attached on `GameManager`

```
void SetTheActiveDice()
{
    diceNumber = Random.Range(0, 6);
    for (int i = 0; i < dices.Count; i++)
    {
        dices[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    if (!dices[diceNumber].gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        print("Not Active");
        dices[diceNumber].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

`dices` contains children of `Dice` from `Dice1` to `Dice6`.
`SetActive` have no effect what so ever, whether I activate or deactivate the object. What is the problem here?

Comment: What kind of effect do you expect to see? Also, can you enable and disable these objects manually in the inspector window?

Comment: The effect that serves the functions purpose to make object active or inactive.

Comment: And yes I can manually change its state in the inspector

Comment: your code works, there must be something wrong somewhere else (calling the function, assigning the dice...).

Comment: Are you sure the code runs?

Comment: Don't know about the `SetActive` in this context but the rest is working.

Comment: Where do you assign the dices?